# Java regarding <E> in public static <E> void

Tags: java

Using Java:
I didn't want to waste peoples time and post this here, but my googling-skills have failed me and I can't find the answer. I was looking through some supplied code and they used

```
public static <E> void printTree(TwoFourTree<E> tf)
```

(For reference we are converting from a Red-Black tree to a Two-Four Tree). When I first approached this problem I would use  instead of  and not even include  in the initial method declaration of `public static void`. However I ran into issues, and throwing in this `<E>` solved all my problems, despite using `<Integer>` instead of `<E>` everywhere else.

So my question is, can someone please explain to me what exactly the `<E>` does in

```
public static <E> void
```

Comment: It's a generic type parameter. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Java feature known as [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Why would you want to use Generics? Well, the following gives one scenario where they are useful. Back in the "bad old days", if you wanted to have a class that could work with any objects you had to declare all it's interfaces in terms of objects, e.g.

```
public class MySuperList
{
    public void Add(object a) { }
}
```

However, this sucks, because you get no type-safety - you could write code like the following:

```
// Your code
MySuperList list = new MySuperList();
cars.Add(new Car("Ford Mondeo"));// Works
cars.Add(new Fish("Herring")); // Works - which is a shame as a Fish is not a car!
```

Generics fixes this, by allowing you to strongly-type your class, but in a generic manner. For example:

```
public class MySuperList<T>
{
    // Add method will only accept instances of type T.
    public void Add(T a) { }
}

// Your code
MySuperList<Cars> list = new MySuperList<Cars>();
cars.Add(new Car("Ford Mondeo"));// Works
cars.Add(new Fish("Herring")); // Compile-time error.
```

Comment: Just a technical thing, but method names generally start with a lower-case letter.

Comment: Sorry - I'm a c# programmer by trade ;)

Answer (score 0):

It creates a *generic method*; i.e. it allows you to use a `TwoFourTree` that holds any type of object as your argument (in this case).

If you, for example, wanted to only accept `TwoFourTree`s that held objects of type `List`, you would define the method as

```
public static <E extends List> void ...
```

If you wanted only `Number` objects (`Integer`, `Double` etc.) you would do

```
public static <E extends Number> void ...
```

This is a reason why creating such methods can in fact be useful. I should point out that the fun doesn't end there, you can do the same using multiple type parameters, for instance:

```
public static <T, S extends Number> void ...
```

I think you might find it beneficial to read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) tutorial on generic methods if you'd like to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing

```
public static Integer ...
public static Double ...
public static Long ...
```

...

all you do is create generics method

```
public static <E>
```

Comment: You can not write `Integer void` method can result with Integer or Void. Please edit or delete your answer.